# Widgets cover each other when using gridlayout inside scrollview

Tags: python, user-interface, scroll, kivy, scrollview

I need to make a playlist like view (such as in Spotify and Apple Music...)
I can't seem to figure this out, the song widgets cover each other at the very button of the scroll view.

This is the SongWidget:

```
class SongWidget(Widget):
    def __init__(self, song, **kwargs):
        super(SongWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.song_obj = song
        self.size_hint_y = None

        self.image = ImageButton()
        self.image.source = ClientDoReqs.gui_src.SONG_BACK
        self.image.size = self.image.texture_size
        self.image.size_hint_y = None
        self.add_widget(self.image)

        self.title = Label()
        self.title.text = "{} | {}".format(self.song_obj.artist, self.song_obj.song_name)
        self.title.size = self.image.size
        self.title.bold = True
        self.title.font_size = 50
        self.title.size_hint_y = None
        self.title.texture_size = (500, None)
        self.title.pos = self.image.x - 425, self.image.y
        self.add_widget(self.title)
```

And this is the PlaylistWidget I made creating the scroll view for the playlist:

```
class PlaylistWidget(ScrollView):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(PlaylistWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.bar_width = 20
        self.size_hint = (1, 0.68)
        self.scroll_type = ['bars']
        self.bar_inactive_color = (5, 20, 10, 0.5)
        self.bar_color = (5, 10, 15, .8)
        self.do_scroll_x = False
        self.do_scroll_y = True

        grid = GridLayout()
        grid.height = 0
        grid.size_hint_y = None
        grid.size_hint_x = 1.0
        grid.cols = 1
        grid.row_default_height = '25dp'
        grid.padding = (5, 5)

        i = 0
        for song in ClientDoReqs.server_songs.songs:
            widg = SongWidget(song)
            widg.size_hint_y = None
            grid.size_hint_x = 1.0

            # increment grid height
            grid.height += widg.height

            grid.add_widget(widg, i)
            i += 1

        self.add_widget(grid)
```

I really could use some help, I'm stuck on this for a while.
THX!

Comment: Looks like your SongWidgets probably all have the default height of 100, which presumably doesn't match the height of their contents.

Comment: So I need to change the label and image heights?

Comment: They stack on eacb other